# How to install DWV piping for new toilets added to current system

Tags: drain-waste-vent, sewer, venting

I am wanting to install a toilet in a cabin that is about 150ft uphill from my home. So waste will run downhill, thank goodness. And about 60 ft from my home on that same run I want to install another toilet in a changing room for hot pool. Then waste line will run into crawl space of house and hook up with 4" sewer line and then into septic tank.

So my questions are what size waste lines and venting lines do I need? And do I just need venting where toilets are? Or do I need vent piping along the 150' run along the way?

And anything else I am leaving out?

Comment: What's the climate? Will you be able to put the waste lines below the frost line?

Comment: Hi Daniel, we live in NW near the Puget Sound so climate is moderate. Not much below freezing for a few weeks of the Winter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to match your 4" house line with 4" to both locations. And yes, if you can toss in an in-line vent halfway along those runs, that would only be beneficial.

And yes again, you'll want to continue the 4" at each location as their own separate vent stacks. Through the roof or higher than all fixtures through the wall.

Additionally, in order to avoid having to vent other fixtures (if any) separately or by tying them into the location's vent stack, you'll need to keep those other drain inlets (if any) no further than 5' from the vent stack. Otherwise no, the vent stack would be just be for the toilet.

Comment: lggy, are you saying that vent stack needs to be 4"? I have seen most are only 2".  A mid way vent stack would be just coming out of the ground going up into the air. I would imagine it would only have to be a few feet above grade. Cover it with a screen to keep varmints out.

Comment: With 150' up in 60' a full size vent will be needed to prevent the solids and waste from being separated

Comment: @topherdig Ed Beal graciously answered the vent sizing. But to expound, a 2" would be easily smothered due to these distances. Like, blowing out a garden hose for winter storage. A 25' hose is easy & needs little air compared to a 100' hose, though they have the same amount of water inside. The Mid-way Vent has a number of benefits. It vents noxious & obnoxious fumes, further assists the soil line flow & is a point of clean-out for a clog. The Pre-Venting prior to the buildings is primary, as the toilets traps may dry-out in a seasonal usage plan.

Comment: Much much gratitude for your direction. I will put all of this into play and get back to you in about a month.

Comment: Get a local plumber's input for an specific ordinances & what not. But, Happy Trenching!